# Creating j2me app that connects  to  facebook ( not the swt project) 

Tags: facebook, api, browser, java-me

I want to create a simple j2me application for a start which links with facebook 
For this ,
I downloaded the facebook api from http://kenai.com/projects/facebookapime/downloads 
Then i followed this site for tutorials http://j2megroup.blogspot.in/2011/06/facebook-api-me-10-tutorial.html

But then for first i got 2 problems 
1) I did not get  Browser class ( it gives a compilation error in eclipse even after adding the external library )
2) I did not got what to put in Redirect uri 
(i got first 2 parameters (App id and App secret but not redirect uri)

later ... when i came to know that its for swt project ... not the j2me pure midlet 
can anyone tell me what's for pure j2me midlet ?

help me with a code snippet or something like that ... that would be preffered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write below code in startApp method
boolean b;
String URL = "Your URL";
b = platformRequest(URL);

destroyApp(true);
notifyDestroyed();
That code will start browser and transffer you on that perticular URL and close your J2ME app.

Comment: Ok But i don't want to close the j2me app and  as per you written i tried the code snippet ... But it closes the app and gives this error 'RUNDLL32.EXE' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. What's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Use
platformRequest(your URL);
May be it will work