# Can a pure j2me app be developed to access facebook

Tags: facebook, java-me

I learned from a link that a third party API is there in j2me for connecting to Facebook.

I got a link as of tutorial
http://j2megroup.blogspot.in/2011/06/facebook-api-me-10-tutorial.html

But then I found it is done for SWT project.

Is there any code for pure j2me code for accessing Facebook?

please help me with the code ... that would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Dude [Check this link](http://kenai.com/projects/facebookapime/downloads) & Download [facebook_api_me-1.0-rim](http://%20facebook_api_me-1.0-rim.zip) try to use that class files in j2me. First try this [FacebookAPIME-RIMSample-1.0 For Blackberry](http://FacebookAPIME-RIMSample-1.0.zip) When it will be done use that same classes to j2me. I hope it will work.

Comment: hey the example is shown for blackberry not for j2me .. i need for j2me

Comment: and it showing error for BrowserField ... it does not get import

Comment: What is redirect Url in this ??

Comment: URL redirection, also called URL forwarding, is a World Wide Web technique for making a web page available under more than one URL address. When a web browser attempts to open a URL that has been redirected, a page with a different URL is opened.

Comment: @Sajid : i tried as per u said to try first in Blackberry ... i read the code in sample example given ... i applied the App secret , App Id and Redirect url too ... but it gave me a runtime exception in Blackberrysimulator ..What's the problem??

Comment: @Sajid:  See i posted this as a question ... check out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920319/running-blackberry-app-in-facebook

and i get a Runtime Exception in BB simulator (JVM Error 104 )

Comment: @Sajid: See i posted this as a question ... check out stackoverflow.com/questions/9920319/… and i get a Runtime Exception in BB simulator (JVM Error 104 ) .. please help me on j2me code if possible

Comment: error_code: 104
error_msg: Incorrect signature     I think your Signature is incorrect.

Comment: @Baba : if its a minor corrections .. please be specific on issue and help out for j2me code

Comment: @Baba & Sajid : What should i do for j2me 
What should i write in startApp()

Comment: @Sajid: i don't want to dwell away from main topic ... that is creating j2me app ... so please help me with j2me thing

Comment: @Sajid: i got one of the answers from this questions .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890825/creating-j2me-app-that-connects-to-facebook-not-the-swt-project